# Select specific fields with google BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase analytics with an app.
When i do:

```
SELECT * FROM `analytics_xxx.events_xxxxx` where event_name="level_quit"
```

it works fine and shows that event values.

When I try to select specific fields or order by specific field I always get a syntax error.

For example:

```
SELECT level_retry FROM `analytics_xxx.events_xxxxx` where event_name="level_quit"
```

I receive an error "Unrecognized name: level_retry at [8:9]"

I am not sure how to use the 'event_params.value.int_value' values in the query and why something that seems simple is getting complicated.

What I am trying to achieve is to display in which levels I got most retires.

This is the result set:
[image]

Comment: `event_params` is a RECORD (_"A repeated record of the parameters associated with this event."_) and `level_retry` is a value of `event_params.key`. It's not a column/field. It's a value. So, you can't select or aggregate by it like that. See here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512#

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @rmesteves just display `level` and `level_retry` for the purpose of this example.

Comment: level and level_retry are values inside a field of a struct as @Graham said. Ordering it doesnt make sense. Can you specify better your problem and what do you want to do?

Comment: @rmesteves updated my comment.

Comment: You want to filter only the rows with level and level_retry in the value for that field?

Comment: @rmesteves yes. I also updated my question about what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(event_name, event_params),
  (SELECT value.int_value FROM t.event_params WHERE key = 'level') AS level,
  (SELECT value.int_value FROM t.event_params WHERE key = 'level_retry') AS level_retry
FROM `project.analytics_xxx.events_xxxxx` t
WHERE event_name = 'level_quit'
```

for the sample in your question - result will be as below

```
Row event_date  event_timestamp     level   level_retry  
1   20200114    1579008893128003    20      0
```

Comment: Thanks, the result does show `level` and `level_retry` but with a big bunch of additional fields like `user_first_touch_timestamp`, `user_ltv.revenue` and many other unuseful fields.

Comment: not sure what you mean? can you please be more specific!? If you are looking for ONLY two fields (level and level_retry) which is not 100% clear from your question - just simply remove following part from query `* EXCEPT(event_name, event_params),` - That simple! please try and let know if still issue

Comment: glad, you made it work for you. please consider also voting up the answer o)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
SELECT t.* EXCEPT (event_params), struct(e) as event_params FROM `analytics_xxx.events_xxxxx` t, t.even_params e
WHERE e.key in UNNEST(['level', 'level_retry'])
```

Please let me know if it helps you

Comment: thanks, but need to display ONLY `level` and `level_retry`

Comment: You want ONLY the the rows with level and level_retry?

Comment: yes, that is what i said, only two fields. i don't need the other data

Comment: Just updated. See if it works for you. Now it filters rows only with level and level_retry

Comment: @Dror its because there are many nested fields in the table. I'll update the answer again to nest the field event_params again after the filter.